# A sequence $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $(0,1)$ where $f, f_n \in C([0,1])$ implies $f_n(0) \to f(0)$, $f_n(1) \to f(1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

This is a past problem for an Applied Math QR Exam:

> Suppose $f_n$, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $f$ are
> continuous functions on the closed interval $[0,1]$. Assume that $f_n \to f$
> as $n \to \infty$ uniformly on the open interval $(0,1)$. Prove
> that
>
> $$ f_n(0) \to f(0) \quad \text{and} \quad f_n(1) \to f(1). $$

Am I wrong to think the proof is just an $\epsilon/3$ argument, at least for $f_n(0) \to f(0)$? If so, then I think that my proof is lacking subtleties to be precise. In particular, I don't think I can give an exact $N = N(\epsilon)$ in applying the definitions. I'm also not sure that proving $f_n(1) \to f(1)$ is any different, except that maybe in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition for, say, $f$, we must say $1 - x < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(1)| < \epsilon$. Lastly, my proof isn't too creative - just application of definitions. So, any more elegant proofs would be of great help, too.

*Proof of $f_n(0) \to f(0)$.* Our goal is to show that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists N$ such that $n > N$ implies $|f_n(0) - f(0)| < \epsilon$.

By assumption, we know that $f, f_n \in \mathcal{C}([0,1])$ tells us

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta_0 > 0 \text{ such that } |x| < \delta_0 \Longrightarrow |f(x) - f(0)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3},$$

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta_1 > 0 \text{ such that } |x| < \delta_1 \Longrightarrow |f_n(x) - f_n(0)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3},$$

and that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $(0,1)$ tells us

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists M \text{ such that } \forall x \in (0,1), n > M \Longrightarrow |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}.$$

Now, for any $x \in (0,1)$, we have

\begin{align*}|f_n(0) - f(0)| &= |f_n(0) - f_n(x) + f_n(x) - f(x) + f(x) - f(0)| \\
&\leq |f_n(x) - f_n(0)| + |f_n(x) - f(x)| + |f(x) - f(0)| \\
&< 3 \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{3} = \epsilon.\end{align*}

So, choosing any $N > M$ and letting $\delta_0, \delta_1 \to 0$ implies $\epsilon \to 0$, and therefore $f_n(0) = f(0)$.

Comment: Your last statement is wrong.  $\varepsilon>0$ is given; it doesn't approach $0$ as $\delta\to 0$..  And you have shown that given any such $\varepsilon$, you can find a number $N$ such that for $n>N$, $|f_n(0)-f(0)|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: So, if I just ended with choosing $N > M$, that would be sufficient? Should I not have to explicitly show that $|f(x) - f(0)|$, $|f_n(x) - f_n(0)| \to 0$? Those terms don't have a relation to $M$. Is that implied in the fact that I'm evaluating $f_n$ and $f$ at $0$, and so $x \to 0$?

Comment: You also have the estimates from continuity.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I still need to fine tune my understanding.